# Великая герцогиня Гессенская Алиса — как правильно?

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика, титулы

Затрудняет выбор прописной или строчной буквы в иностранном титуле.
Как правильно: ***Великая*** герцогиня Гессенская или ***великая*** герцогиня Гессенская?
А может, есть еще какой-то вариант: великая герцогиня гессенская?

Answer (score 2):

Алиса
(Мод Мари)
**великая герцогиня Гессенская** (25 апр. 1843 — 14 дек. 1878); вторая дочь английской королевы Виктории и принца Альберта.
[Энциклопедический словарь Ф.А. Брокгауза и И.А. Ефрона. 1890—1907](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/brokgauz_efron/3213)

Али́са Великобрита́нская (англ. Alice of the United Kingdom), также Али́са Са́ксен-Ко́бург-Го́тская (англ. Alice of Saxe-Coburg and Gotha); в замужестве — **великая герцогиня Гессенская**.
[Алиса (великая герцогиня Гессенская)](https://wiki2.org/ru/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_(%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F))

**Алиса Великобританская, великая герцогиня Гессенская**
American English-Russian dictionary. Американский англо-русский словарь. 2012

Гессенская (*Гессенская и Рейнская* или *Гессенская и Прирейнская*) — титул по названию герцогства — с прописной; "великая" — со строчной (герцогство — часть государства).